# Couldn't clone socket.io submodules

Tags: git, socket.io, git-submodules

```
C:\Users\raj\Desktop>git clone --recursive -j8 https://github.com/saikat/DrawTogether.git
Cloning into 'DrawTogether'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 505, done.
remote: Total 505 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 505
Receiving objects: 100% (505/505), 1.04 MiB | 2.10 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (75/75), done.
Submodule 'lib/socket.io' (git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node.git) registered for path 'lib/socket.io'
Cloning into 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.205.243.166]: errno=Unknown error

fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io' failed
Failed to clone 'lib/socket.io'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.205.243.166]: errno=Unknown error

fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io' failed
Failed to clone 'lib/socket.io' a second time, aborting
```

After that I've tried-

> git submodule init
> git submodule update

```
Cloning into 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io'...    fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0:
   20.205.243.166]: errno=Unknown error
       fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node.git' into    submodule path 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io'    failed Failed to clone 'lib/socket.io'. Retry scheduled Cloning into    'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io'... fatal: unable to    connect to github.com: github.com[0: 20.205.243.166]: errno=Unknown    error
       fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node.git' into    submodule path 'C:/Users/raj/Desktop/DrawTogether/lib/socket.io'    failed Failed to clone 'lib/socket.io' a second time, aborting
```

**giving same error as before. couldn't figure out!!**

Comment: See phd's answer; you might also lodge an issue with the owner of the repository you cloned, although it looks like abandonware (last updated 12 years ago, and [an issue filed 11 years ago saying it doesn't work any more](https://github.com/saikat/DrawTogether/issues/2)!).

Answer (score 1):

In the repository https://github.com/saikat/DrawTogether [the submodule is declared with `git://` protocol](https://github.com/saikat/DrawTogether/blob/907c13d35119840ffa506884914a46595c066779/.gitmodules#L3) but [the protocol was disabled at Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72916549/7976758) long ago. The repository must be fixed by changing the protocol to `https://`.

Meanwhile you can use [`url..insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) to fix URLs on the fly:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com.insteadOf git://github.com
```

and then clone again or update the submodule:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/saikat/DrawTogether.git
```

or

```
cd DrawTogether
git submodule update --recursive
```