# Git submodule fails to load due to outdated, invalid protocol

Tags: git, drupal, git-submodules

My company acquired a Drupal website with a complicated build process, using dozens of submodules. I'm using the following command to check out the repository and install submodules.

```
git clone --recursive  <.git URL copied from GitHub>
```

When the install process makes it to the `microdata` submodule, it fails every time:

```
Submodule 'tests/MicrodataPHP' (git://github.com/linclark/MicrodataPHP.git) registered for path 'src/sites/all/modules/contrib/microdata/tests/MicrodataPHP'
Cloning into '<local path>/src/sites/all/modules/contrib/microdata/tests/MicrodataPHP'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.113.3]: errno=Operation timed out

fatal: clone of 'git://github.com/linclark/MicrodataPHP.git' into submodule path '<local path>/src/sites/all/modules/contrib/microdata/tests/MicrodataPHP' failed
```

I've tried

- Cloning the MicrodataPHP repo (it works just fine with HTTPS and GIT URLs)
- Removing references to microdata from my project
- Changing microdata URLs from HTTP to HTTPS
- Downloading the Drupal microdata repo and adding to my project directly.
- Downloading the MicrodataPHP repo and adding it directly to my project

Unfortunately nothing works. I need to make a single change to this repository to update the Google Analytics ID, but I can't build locally to confirm. And when I just push up a PR with that simple text change, my build fails in Travis with the same error, which means we can't get it to deploy. And I can't make the change directly in production because this site uses Docker Swarm.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get around this issue? Alternately does anyone have a way to update this single line text change without requiring a rebuild of the entire site?

Comment: The submodule `tests/MicrodataPHP` uses URL with `git://` protocol but the protocol was disabled at Github long ago, Use `git config --global url.https://github.com.insteadOf git://github.com` to make Git to always use `https://` instead of `git://` at GH. See for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74087755/7976758

Comment: Mind blown! That was it!! Would you please repost this as an answer instead of a comment so that I can select it Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submodule `tests/MicrodataPHP` uses URL with `git://` protocol but [the protocol was disabled at Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72916549/7976758) long ago. Use

```
git config --global url.https://github.com.insteadOf git://github.com
```

to make Git to always use `https://` instead of `git://` at GH. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf).

Comment: This did the trick, and now my build is green! I just added it to my travis.yml file right before the call to `git submodule update --init --recursive`. Thank you @phd!