# get `Error installing libpd-ios` on `pod install`

Tags: xcode

When `pod install` I get

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing libpd-ios (0.11.0)

[!] Error installing libpd-ios
[!] /usr/bin/git -C /var/folders/2w/0wtczkq94c9ch_y6m89gg29m0000jq/T/d20221207-77916-57ccbt submodule update --init --recursive

Submodule 'jni/opensl_stream' (git://github.com/nettoyeurny/opensl_stream.git) registered for path 'jni/opensl_stream'
Submodule 'pure-data' (git://git.code.sf.net/p/pure-data/pure-data) registered for path 'pure-data'
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/2w/0wtczkq94c9ch_y6m89gg29m0000jq/T/d20221207-77916-57ccbt/jni/opensl_stream'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Operation timed out
```

according to [fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Operation timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72915782/fatal-unable-to-connect-to-github-com-github-com0-140-82-121-3-errno-opera) this is related to ssh

but how do I fix it?