# What is the command format for bitbake recipietool that uses github with ssh access?

Tags: git, yocto, devtools, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I have tried all kinds of URL formats with recipetool but nothing seems to work with my github url.

URL to use : `git@github.com/<username>/repo1.git`

```
recipetool create git@github.com:<username>/repo1.git
```

I keep getting error as follows:

```
NOTE: Starting bitbake server...
INFO: Fetching git://git@github.com/username/cip_linux-cip.git;protocol=ssh;branch=master...
Loading cache: 100% |####################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1799 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/meta-custom/recipes-recipetool/recipetool/tmp-recipetool-o77j2dqj.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py", line 253, in Git.urldata_init(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f1beca5dff0>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f1beca5dab0>):
     
    >        ud.setup_revisions(d)
     
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1354, in FetchData.setup_revisions(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f1beca5dab0>):
             for name in self.names:
    >            self.revisions[name] = srcrev_internal_helper(self, d, name)
     
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1221, in srcrev_internal_helper(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f1beca5dff0>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f1beca5dab0>, name='default'):
             d.setVar("__BBAUTOREV_ACTED_UPON", True)
    >        srcrev = ud.method.latest_revision(ud, d, name)
     
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/__init__.py", line 1631, in Git.latest_revision(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f1beca5dff0>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f1beca5dab0>, name='default'):
             except KeyError:
    >            revs[key] = rev = self._latest_revision(ud, d, name)
                 return rev
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/fetch2/git.py", line 759, in Git._latest_revision(ud=<bb.fetch2.FetchData object at 0x7f1beca5dff0>, d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f1beca5dab0>, name='default'):
                         return sha1
    >        raise bb.fetch2.FetchError("Unable to resolve '%s' in upstream git repository in git ls-remote output for %s" % \
                 (ud.unresolvedrev[name], ud.host+ud.path))
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable SRCPV, expression was ${@bb.fetch2.get_srcrev(d)} which triggered exception FetchError: Fetcher failure: Unable to resolve 'master' in upstream git repository in git ls-remote output for github.com/username/cip_linux-cip.git
The variable dependency chain for the failure is: SRCPV -> PV -> BP -> FILESPATH

ERROR: Parsing halted due to errors, see error messages above

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/scripts/recipetool", line 111, in <module>
    ret = main()
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/scripts/recipetool", line 100, in main
    ret = args.func(args)
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/scripts/lib/recipetool/create.py", line 492, in create_recipe
    checksums, ftmpdir = scriptutils.fetch_url(tinfoil, fetchuri, srcrev, srctree, logger, preserve_tmp=args.keep_temp)
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/scripts/lib/scriptutils.py", line 197, in fetch_url
    tinfoil.parse_recipes()
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/tinfoil.py", line 449, in parse_recipes
    self.run_actions(config_params)
  File "/home/preetam/Workspace/cip-yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/tinfoil.py", line 432, in run_actions
    raise TinfoilUIException(ret)
bb.tinfoil.TinfoilUIException: 1
```

Comment: Syntax `git@github.com/<username>/repo1.git` is wrong for SSH protocol; the correct syntax is `git@github.com:<username>/repo1.git` (note colon). `git://` protocol was disabled at GitHUb long ago. Try `ssh://git@github.com/<username>/repo1.git` (explicit SSH protocol; note it's again slash, not colon). References: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls , https://stackoverflow.com/a/72916549/7976758

Comment: I did try that as well. It didn't work. Same error. I am not sure why but this seems to have worked for me: `git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git`. Also the -o has to be after the url not before. I needed both these changes to generate something.